# Создание страниц в php

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Можно ли создать програмно страницу php?

Comment: Можно, конечно, а вам на каком языке надо? И зачем? И причем здесь `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Мне в php надо создать php. Ну как в соц. сетях

Comment: А какая проблема? Обыкновенный текстовый файл, только с расширением `php`.

Comment: Мне програмно надо. Какая функция?

Comment: Попробуйте гугл, он помогает, реально! Мне помог: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+write+text+file -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Там и пример был:

    <?php
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, '1');
    fwrite($fp, '23');
    fclose($fp);
    ?>

Клёво, правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'w', '666');
fwrite($fh, "...");
fclose($fh);
require_once($file);

return new $file_classname();
```

$file - название файла,
file_classname - название класса, созданного в этом файле.

Вот только зачем это???

> > Ну как в соц. сетях (профили пользователей)

Там не php-файлы создаются, а html-страницы формируются на основе различных исходных данных.

Надо сначала про PHP почитать, а потом уже "как в соц. сетях" делать.